# How to use mask in angular-xeditable?

Tags: angularjs, mask, x-editable

I need to connect the mask to angular-xeditable. 
So I connect the mask to angularjs.

```
<input id="phone" name="firstName" type="text" class="form-control mb5"  placeholder="(999) 999-9999" ng-model="vm.phoneNumber" ui-jq="mask" ui-options="'(999) 999-9999'">
```

But I don't understand how to connect angular-xeditable

```
<span id="phone" editable-text="vm.phone" e-placeholder="(999) 999-9999" e-form="tableform" onbeforesave="checkName3($data)">
   {{vm.phone || '-'}}
 </span>
```

This option does not work.

Comment: Can you describe the symptoms as well as what you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this "e-*"

```
<span id="phone" editable-text="vm.phone" 
   e-placeholder="(999) 999-9999" 
   e-form="tableform" 
   e-ui-jq="mask" 
   e-ui-options="'(999) 999-9999'" 
   onbeforesave="checkName3($data)"> {{vm.phone || '-'}}
</span>
```

Other Option:

include js

```
/bower_components/jquery.inputmask/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js   



<span editable-text="ApTax" e-size="50" e-maxlength="50"
                              e-ng-model="ApTax" e-id="ApTax"
                              e-maskinput e-data-inputmask="'mask':'999-***'"
                              e-name="BAS" e-form="rowform" e-required>
                            {{ ApTax}}
 </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [angular-ui-mask](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask) for checking mask.

Just install it:

```
bower install angular-ui-mask
```

Load the script file in your html (scripts for [angular-xeditable](http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/) you've already loaded, i hope):

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-mask/dist/mask.js"></script>
```

Add the specific module to your dependencies:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.mask', ...])
```

And your code is:

```
<span id="phone" editable-text="vm.phone" 
      e-ui-mask="(999) 999-9999" e-form="tableform"
      onbeforesave="checkName3($data)">
      {{vm.phone || '-'}}
</span>
```

Note, that for angular-xeditable you need to use angular-ui-mask's attributes with prefix "e-", for example "e-ui-mask".